# what is difference between while(true) and while(new Scanner(System.in).hasNext)

Tags: java, while-loop

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while(true){             
    TreeSet<Integer> set=new TreeSet<Integer>();
    int n=sc.nextInt();

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        set.add(sc.nextInt());
    }

    for(Integer i:set){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

The code above gives `Index out of bounds`; but when I use `sc.hasNext()`, it works. why?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
while(sc.hasNext()){

    TreeSet<Integer> set=new TreeSet<Integer>();
    int n=sc.nextInt();

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        set.add(sc.nextInt());
    }

    for(Integer i:set){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Link not opening...

Comment: `while(true)` is never ending unless you `break`  or `return` out of it.

Comment: Please post your code in the question, not as a link (not even if the link worked).

Comment: Instead of image, paste the code! If you paste the code, we can copy it and check it. Don't expect us to type all those code.

Comment: You should look at the preview before you submit the question...

Comment: We need more detail here. Is `System.in` tied to the keyboard, to a file, or to what? Can you post a stacktrace and indicate which line in the posted code the stacktrace referes to?

Comment: I am practice in an OJ plateform .https://www.nowcoder.com/practice/3245215fffb84b7b81285493eae92ff0?tpId=37&tqId=21226&rp=&ru=/ta/huawei&qru=/ta/huawei/question-ranking

Answer (score 0):

Essentially

```
while(true) {
     //some code
}
```

will run forever unless you use `break` somehow.

```
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    //some code
}
```

will stop running when `Scanner sc` will have nothing to read any more or you use `break` keyword.

Comment: yes, your are right, but why it cause errors like index out of bounds ?

Comment: none of `true` and `sc.hasNext()` cause `indexOutOfBoundsException`. It must be somewhere else in your code. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and ask another question with code snippet, exception stacktrace (this text with many informations) and then we'll be able to help.

Comment: @bore2015 for what input do you get Exception? cannot reproduce

Comment: I am practice in an OJ plateform https://www.nowcoder.com/practice/3245215fffb84b7b81285493eae92ff0?tpId=37&tqId=21226&rp=&ru=/ta/huawei&qru=/ta/huawei/question-ranking